# Can't run boinc on fedora

Tags: networking, software-installation

I'm trying to install boinc to fedora 17 from packages.
Everything is fine, client starts properly, I added port 31416 to firewall exception.

However cannot add any project or execute any command on it.
boincmgr cannot connect to the core client
any command on boinccmd returns 
status: Error -1
Operation failed: Error -1

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

cd to the boinc_client working directory before issuing a command

So if your boinc_client has its' working directory as /var/lib/boinc, then cd to that and then issue the boinccmd commands.

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems:

- You don't have WxWidgets installed
- SELinux is interfering (try disabling it)
- The user running the BOINC manager isn't in the BOINC group